# Excel formula Index and Match doesn't update when dragging down

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, updating

I have the following formula

=INDEX($D$2:$D$300018,MATCH($AA$3,$O$2:$O$300018,0))

When I drag down the formula it doesn't change $AA$3 to corresponding Row

Please help

Comment: Remove the `$` in front of the 3.

Comment: Thanks that worked

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$300018,MATCH($AA$3,$O$2:$O$300018,0))
```

with:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$300018,MATCH($AA3,$O$2:$O$300018,0))
```